# how to convert json data to xml and read xml data and draw a rectangle in html5?

Tags: xml, html

This is my JSON data : data.json

```
{
    "Frame_count":1,
    "output":[
        {
        "Objects_classname":"car1",
            "x_val":82.9883,
            "y_val":197.56245,
            "width":316.03088,
            "height":197.45451
        },

        {
        "Objects_classname":"car2",
            "x_val":522.4823,
            "y_val":170.47263,
            "width":64.66687,
            "height":61.78085
        },

        ]
        "Total_objects_detected":2,
},
{
    "Frame_count":2,
    "output":[
        {
        "Objects_classname":"car1",
            "x_val":123.68143,
            "y_val":201.01093,
            "width":297.69861,
            "height":189.92859
        },

        ]
        "Total_objects_detected":1,
}
```

I want to convert this JSON data into valid XML file format.

Next step is to read this XML data in HTML5 and it should draw a rectangle.

Here I am giving HTML code to draw rectangle using JSON data. similarly, I want it into XML format.

```
 var local_data = data;
        window.setInterval(ctx1.rect(local_data[j].output[k].x_val, local_data[j].output[k].y_val, local_data[j].output[k].width,local_data[j].output[k].height)
```

Comment: Why convert to XML first?

Comment: Because I don't wish to continue with JSON. And I am working on PASCAL VOC format(you can say XML format) for object detection part. That's why I need to work on XML

Comment: Then your question is not defined enough. You must **1)** show the XML you want to generate from the JSON sample, **2)** clearly define any rules and edge cases for the JSON and the XML format, **3)** detail where you want to transform it (On the client? The server? Which programming language is being used). You should also make a mention of Pascal VOC in the question text, this is a relevant detail.

Comment: @Tomalak Ya sure, I am sharing XML format. XML format : `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<root>
  <annotation>
    <frame>1</frame>
    <output>
      <type>class</type>
      <text>car1</text>
    </output>
    <output>
      <type>x_val</type>
      <text>341</text>
    </output>
    <output>
      <type>y_val</type>
      <text>120</text>
    </output>
    <output>
      <type>width</type>
      <text>341</text>
    </output>
    <output>
      <type>height</type>
      <text>541</text>
    </output>
     </annotation>
  </root>`

Comment: @Tomalak In that I want is Frame by Frame data in my HTML page.

Comment: @Tomalak Currently, I am working in local system only so no need of any server and client communication. If it is not happening without server than only I need.

Comment: @Tomalak please follow new XML format:  XML format : `<root>
  <annotation>
    <Frame>1</Frame>
    <Total_obj>1</Total_obj>
    <output>
      <Objects_class>car1</Objects_class>
      <x_val>34</x_val>
      <y_val>23</y_val>
      <width>22</width>
      <height>13</height>
    </output>
  </annotation>
  <annotation>
    <Frame>2</Frame>
    <Total_obj>2</Total_obj>
    <output>
      <Objects_class>car1</Objects_class>
      <x_val>34</x_val>
      <y_val>23</y_val>
      <width>22</width>
      <height>13</height>
    </output>
  </annotation>
</root>`